# mismatch in input_shape and model structure

Tags: python, keras, lstm

This is the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24, input_shape = (trainX.shape[0], 1, 4)))
model.add(Dense(12, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

And after running, I got this:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Can anyone explain this to me? and the relationship between input_shape and model structure.

Comment: trainX.shape[0] = 104458, it's the whole number of my datset

Comment: what is the trainX.shape? is it (104458,1,3)?

Answer (score 1):

Your `input_shape` should be `(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])`. `trainX.shape[0]` is the number of training samples, which `input_shape` doesn't care about; `input_shape` only cares about the dimension of each sample, which is in the form `(timesteps, features)`.

```
model.add(LSTM(24, input_shape = (trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
```